# magento 2.2 static content deploy errors

Tags: magento2.2, css, static-content-deploy

I am trying to deploy static content in developer mode in magento 2.2 community edition. I am getting multiple errors in terminal related to css.

Getting error as -

> [Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException]
>     Cannot read contents from file "/var/www/html/[site]/staging/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/Mysite_Theme/css/less/type.css" Warning!file_get_contents(/var/www/html/[Site]/staging/pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/Mysite_Theme/css/less/type.css): failed to open stream: No such file or directory   .

I checked for the file type.css, there is no file present in the project with such name.

Please provide a solution.

Comment: are you create custom theme?

Answer (score 0):

Make you sure your theme path is like below:

```
/app/design/frontend/Mysite/Theme/
```

Comment: My theme path is app/design/frontend/Magento/blank /

Comment: You have to create a theme like this:
app/design/frontend/Mysite/Theme/registration.php

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/thezme-create.html